# What c++ version does CodeBlocks 13.12 use?

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I'm reading C++ Primer and there are some pieces of code that reqiure C++11. I know how to set the compiler to use this version, but I was wondering what it uses by default.

Comment: Cross site dup: https://superuser.com/questions/206157/checking-version-of-gcc-compiler-in-codeblocks

Comment: Coupled with this https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Answer (score 2):

Codeblocks 13.12, which is only available for Mac, is a few years old and does not come bundled with any GCC. It's going to use whatever's available on your system. More than likely GCC on a Mac will actually be symlinked to Clang. Running `gcc -v` or `clang++ -v` should tell you the headers that are being used for compatibility.